# Mail Error - >You must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, phpmailer, forgot-password

i am using php mailer to send forget password links to users this is my code

```
<?php require "config.php";?>
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer\src\Exception.php';

/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require 'PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php';

/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require 'PHPMailer\src\SMTP.php';


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Forgot Password System</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
      <p>Enter Email Address To Send Password Link</p>
      <input type="text" name="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit_email">
    </form>
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit_email']) && $_POST['email'])
{
 $email = $_POST['email'];
  $select=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email,password from users where email='$email'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($select)==1)
  {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
    {
      $email=md5($row['email']);
      $pass=md5($row['password']);
    }
    $link="<a href='www.samplewebsite.com/reset.php?key=".$email."&reset=".$pass."'>Click To Reset password</a>";


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  
    // GMAIL username
    $mail->Username = "your_email_id@gmail.com";
    // GMAIL password
    $mail->Password = "your_gmail_password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
    // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Port = "465";
    $mail->From='your_gmail_id@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName='your_name';
    $mail->AddAddress('reciever_email_id', 'reciever_name');
    $mail->Subject  =  'Reset Password';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body    = 'Click On This Link to Reset Password '.$pass.'';
    if($mail->Send())
    {
      echo "Check Your Email and Click on the link sent to your email";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
  } 
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

i am having this error when i click on submit button Mail Error - >You must provide at least one recipient email address. i dont know what am i doing wrong
actually i copied this code for my website i dont know whats wrong in this code and why it is showing me this error

Comment: You don't tell it where to send the mail to... `'receiver_email_id'` is a string, which is not an e-mail address.

Comment: how to use the value that is given by user

Comment: Use `$row['email']` I guess?

Comment: As an aside, md5 (especially without a salt) is not secure in any way. And you have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: `$mail->addAddress($email);`

Comment: @Stender $email ends up as an md5 hash.

Comment: ^^ helpfull - but that is where he should add recipients..

Comment: so.... `$mail->addAddress($row['email']);`

Comment: wait... he is outside the while loop - So that won't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines

```
$mail->From='your_gmail_id@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress('reciever_email_id', 'reciever_name');
```

with this

```
$mail->setFrom('your_gmail_id@gmail.com', 'mailer_name'); 
$mail->addAddress('reciever_email_id@gmail.com');
```

[check example email](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) for more information

for below error (As per your comment )

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; //add this host
```

and check `open_ssl` extension and change `port 465` to `587`

here is the complete code

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;   
    $mail->isSMTP();
// change this to 0 if the site is going live
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

 //use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "******";
    $mail->setFrom('xxx@ww.com', 'Somebody');
    $mail->addReplyTo('xxx@ww.com', 'Somebody');
    $mail->addAddress('xxx@ww.com', 'Somebody');
    $mail->Subject = 'New contact from somebody';
    // $message is gotten from the form
    $mail->msgHTML($message);
$mail->AltBody = $filteredmessage;
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "We are extremely sorry to inform you that your message
could not be delivered,please try again.";
    } else {
        echo "Your message was successfully delivered,you would be contacted shortly.";
        }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522542/how-to-send-e-mail-from-localhost-with-phpmailer)

Comment: it worked but now it is showing another error  Mail Error - >SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: add this host `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`

Comment: still  not solving

Comment: have you checked `open_ssl ` extension?

Comment: i am on localhost

Comment: This started out well... If you specify `ssl` in the `Host` property, it overrides what is in `SMTPSecure`, and the combination of `ssl` mode and `Port = 587` will not work. It was fine as it was. A better example to use in this case is [the gmail one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).